# replacing the column with next column values

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

```
ADRLN1                                   ADRLN2                                   ADRLN3                                   ADRLN4                                   ADRCIT                    ADRSTA                    ADRCNY                    ADDRESS
---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
Tsrdl                                    address1                                 address2                                  dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf              Alibaug                   Maharashtra               India                     412001
aaa aa Ltd.                              Mahalaxmi                                                                                                                  Mumbai                    Maharashtra                                         400011
190, SANDESH VIHAR (P&T)                 DELHI                                                                                                                                                                                                    110034
6/2/A LLOYDS GARDEN                      APPASAHEB MARATHE MARG                   PRABHADEVI                               MUMBAI                                                                                                                 400025
```

the above data is reflected from the data base using select  query

OUTPUT:

```
ADRLN1                                   ADRLN2                                   ADRLN3                                   ADRLN4                                   ADRCIT                    ADRSTA                    ADRCNY                    ADDRESS
---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ------------------------- ----------
Tsrdl                                    address1                                 address2                                  dfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf              Alibaug                   Maharashtra               India                     412001
aaa aa Ltd.                              Mahalaxmi                                Mumbai                                    Maharashtra                             400011
190, SANDESH VIHAR (P&T)                 DELHI                                    110034
6/2/A LLOYDS GARDEN                      APPASAHEB MARATHE MARG                   PRABHADEVI                               MUMBAI                                   400025
```

I need the output in following manner .
Suppose if any column is blank  then it should replace by next column values.

Comment: please check the adrln3 values 
in first output it is blank and in next output it has next column values

Comment: You might want to edit the sample data to show the *relevant* columns only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use coalesce. For example,

```
select coalesce (ADRLN1, ADRLN2, ADRLN3, ADRLN4 ) as ADRLN1 
  coalesce (ADRLN2, ADRLN3, ADRLN4 ) as ADRLN2,
  coalesce (ADRLN3, ADRLN4 ) as ADRLN3,
  ADRLN2 as ADRLN2
from table;
```

But you should go ahead with logic to really shift your column.

**Edit**: Seems you want to eliminate "gaps" in the address.

A trick you can do is to select the concatenation of columns:

```
select decode(ADRLN3, null, null, ADRLN3||',')||
   decode(ADRLN4, null, null, ADRLN4||',')||
   decode(ADRCIT, null, null, ADRCIT||',')||
   decode(ADRSTA, null, null, ADRSTA||',')||
   decode(ADRCNY, null, null, ADRCNY||',')||
   ADDRESS  as ADDRESS
from table;
```

Comment: @ Florin Ghita  thanks ur trick work